# Taylor series with function composition

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Pretty simple, but I want to take the first order taylor series expansion of the following:

$f(g(x,y+Δy))$

Would the following be correct?

$f(g(x,y+Δy)) = f(g(x,y) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,y)*Δy)$

$= f(g(x,y)) + \frac{\partial}{\partial g}f(g(x,y))*\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,y)*Δy$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. In fact, since $x$ never changes, we don't have to recognize it as a variable at all. Just consider $g$ as a function of $y$ only. The chain rule says that $(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)g'$, and rewriting this in terms of differentials gives the result.